# Probability game (coin-tossing)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Two players play a coin-tossing game where they flip a fair coin and record the outcomes. Each player has a distinct victory condition that involves the sequence of the last two flips. Player 1's condition for winning is obtaining two consecutive 1 while player 2's condition for winning is getting two consecutive 0. The game ends as soon as one of the players' winning conditions is met. Determine the probability of Player 1 winning the game.

My idea: Player $1$ wins if and only if in string of outcomes (let it be S) there are no $00$ substrings and two last digits are "1" (also there are no $11$ substrings except for this).
It's easy to see that for fixed $n$ there's only one such string ($S = "...101011"$) and probability of occuring is $\frac{1}{2^n}$. My question - is probability of winning is just $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$ or am I missing something?

Comment: I am unclear.  Do the consecutive $1$s  have to both be by player 1, or do they have to be by Player 2 and then Player 1, or can they either be by Player 2 and then Player 1 or by  Player 1 and then Player 2?  In the first two interpretations Player 1 has the advantage of starting first, while in the third interpretation there is an obvious symmetry.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything and the answer is right ($= 1/2$), but it's worth pointing out that it must equal $1/2$ by symmetry. Strictly speaking, this requires showing that the game ends with probability $1$, which your method does, but this "shortcut" allows you to divine the answer faster at the cost of some rigor.

Comment: @Henry: Oh, I thought they just collectively flipped a coin and tracked the results.

Comment: @BrianTung - you may be correct.

Comment: @Henry I'm unsure too because originally task was like this, so I assumed we have both players writing by queue...

Comment: @BrianTung Okay, thank you, will note :)